# I want get parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get this `li`, where i find `mega-current-menu-item`  parent `ul` class. Please help me.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  {
         if (jQuery("li").hasClass("mega-current-menu-item")) {
            console.log(jQuery(this).parent());

         }
  };
});
```

Comment: tHello there, try this ``console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'))``, I hope that helps.

Comment: @OrisSin it's display me "undefined"

Comment: Your `this` does not refer to the `li`. Try starting with `jQuery('li.mega-current-menu-item').parent()` to get all the parents, and you can use `.each()` to check their classes. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this, it must work definitely. I have tested in my localhost.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("li").hasClass("mega-current-menu-item")) {
            var li = $("li.mega-current-menu-item")
            console.log(li.parent().attr('class'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes i have get class, bus how i can to appropriate the style to this one that I received, since I have a lot of such classes?I have a lot of "ul" with such a class, but I need to assign a style to this one that was taken

Comment: A lot of ``ul`` elements or ``li`` items ? I don't really grasp what you really need. Your question then is a bit ambiguous.